# $\sigma$ finiteness of locally compact groups with haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

To my understanding, the Haar-measure on a locally compact group $G$ is inner regular on all open subsets and compact subsets have finite measure. Why then would the group itself, being open, not be $\sigma$-finite? Couldn't we find a sequence of compact subsets, all with finite measure, whose measure converges (or diverges to infinity) to the measure of the group, making it $\sigma$-finite?

If it turns out that not all locally compact groups are $\sigma$-finite, does fubini's theorem still hold?

Comment: The condition you state about a sequence of subsets with finite measure is not the definition of $\sigma$-finite...

Comment: Indeed, not every LCG is $\sigma$-finite with respect to Haar measure (consider any uncountable group with the discrete topology).  However Fubini's theorem still works most of the time,  since most functions dealt with vanish outside some $\sigma$-compact set.  Section 2.2 of Folland's *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* deals exactly with the concerns you have, so I would recommend reading that.

Comment: I was mistaken, you're quite right, my assumed definition of $\sigma$-finite is wrong. Nevertheless the comments have helped me find the required reference, so it was well worth it anyway.

Comment: In the second edition of Folland's book, this is section 2.3 Interlude: Some Technicalities.